# Customize Browse Fragment

Tags: android, android-styles, android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

I wish to customize Browse fragment via width that distinguishes header and child fragment in Browse Fragment. The default ratio of distinction is about 1:3 but I wish space took by header fragment to be reduced (e.g in the ratio 1:4). After some research, I found padding and margins only for them modifying from styles.xml but which is not my requirement.
What is the solution to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Solution was to override dimensions of the leanback library with the same resources name in the dimens.xml of my own project.